# Csv to Mysql INSERT INTO the last row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem, when I import a data from .csv file to Mysql, this data is inserted in a new row. I want this data next to the other cells, in the same row.
I have an auto-incremental Id,and the default/expression of the columns is NULL. I don't know where is the problem.
Can you help me?
Thanks!!

Comment: Add your table schema, example of CSV records and expected result to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the imported data rows have some columns that have values in common with the existing data (auto-incrementing IDs won't do it), import the data into a temporary table, then use an UPDATE statement to join your base table to the temporary table on the common columns, and transfer the data from the temporary table to the base table.